# How does MySQL 8.0 Hash Join support even no condition or non-equi-join?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0

In MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, [Hash Join Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html), it says that a hash join is also applied for a **Cartesian product** and Inner **non-equi-join** can also be optimized using hash joins.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN FORMAT=TREE
    -> SELECT *
    ->     FROM t1
    ->     JOIN t2
    ->     WHERE t1.c2 > 50\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: -> Inner hash join (no condition) (cost=0.70 rows=1)
    -> Table scan on t2  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
    -> Hash
        -> Filter: (t1.c2 > 50)  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
            -> Table scan on t1  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
```

Also in [MySQL Worklog 13377](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13377), it seems that no hash table is build(not sure)?

> SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 < t2.col1;

> In order to execute this query using hash join, we will do a cross-join between t1 and t2, and **attach the join condition as a filter after the join**. The execution plan will look like this:

```
-> Filter: (t1.col1 < t2.col1)  (cost=0.70 rows=1)
    -> Inner hash join (no condition)  (cost=0.70 rows=1)
        -> Table scan on t2  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
        -> Hash
            -> Table scan on t1  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
```

There is a **(no condition)** in the explain result. I am curious of the explain result as Hash Join could not speed up the queries in these cases.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the tables?  What does `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` give?

Comment: Do a plain `EXPLAIN`.  Does that say "Using join buffer (hash join)"?

Comment: @RickJames Yes it is, you could test with any two small tables.